# Node.js net module does not recognize Chinese, Korean, and other double byte character

Tags: node.js, telnet, cjk

When I use `client.write` in the net module, it only recognizes English, Numbers, and other ASCII symbols.

```js
const net = require("net");
const server = net.createServer();

server.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.write('中文 한글');  // some double byte unicode characters
});
```

I tried to encode to CP949 or CP950 but it does not help.

The text I get:
[Screenshot Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnLrb.png)

It is not as the text I wrote in the code.

Comment: Have you tried [`setEncoding()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setencoding_encoding)?

Comment: The characters are still broken.